# Login Facebook in Java

Tags: java, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to write Login to Facebook in Java. This is my code, I can't understand were my mistake is.

```
package org.testLogin.com;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Cookie;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
//import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;

public class FormLogin {
    static final String LOGON_SITE = "www.facebook.com";
    static final int LOGON_PORT = 443;

    public FormLogin() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws HttpException, IOException {
        // Set target URL
        String strURL = "http://www.facebook.com";
        System.out.println("Target URL: " + strURL);
        // Get initial state object
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        // ---------Help Code-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params,
                org.apache.http.HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params,"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8");
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);
//      HttpProtocolParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 1000);
//      HttpProtocolParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
        SchemeRegistry supportedschemes = new SchemeRegistry();
        supportedschemes.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));
        supportedschemes.register(new Scheme("https",
                (SocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(), 443));
        // .getSocketFactory()
        ClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                params, supportedschemes);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager,
                params);

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod(strURL);
        // Execute HTTP GET
        int result = httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
        // Display status code
        System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
        // Get all the cookies
        Cookie[] cookies = httpclient.getState().getCookies();
        // Display the cookies
        System.out.println("Present cookies: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" - " + cookies[i].toExternalForm());
        }
        // Release current connection to the connection pool
        httpget.releaseConnection();
        // Cookie
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(
                "https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
//      int resultPost= httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        Cookie[] cookies1= httpclient.getState().getCookies();
        String CookieLsd = null;
        for(int j=0; j<cookies1.length;j++)
        {
            String Check= cookies1[j].toString();
            if(Check=="lsd")
            {
//              CookieLsd= Check;
                System.out.println(Check);
            }   
        }
        NameValuePair[] postData = new NameValuePair[6];
        postData[0] = new NameValuePair("locale", "en_US");
        postData[1] = new NameValuePair("non_com_login", "");
        postData[2] = new NameValuePair("email", "********");
        postData[3] = new NameValuePair("pass", "********");
        postData[4] = new NameValuePair("lsd", CookieLsd);
        postData[5]= new NameValuePair("charset_test", "**************");
        postMethod.setRequestBody(postData);

        int responsePage = httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        // for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){
        // postMethod.setRequestHeader("Cookie:",cookies[i].toExternalForm());
        // }
        try {
            httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod);
        }
        // int statuscode = postMethod.getStatusCode();
        // System.out.println("STATUS CODE = " + statuscode);
        catch (HttpException httpe) {
            System.err.print("HttpException");
            System.err.println(httpe.getMessage());
            httpe.printStackTrace();
        }

        // catch (IOException ioe) {
        // System.err.print("IOException");
        // System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        // ioe.printStackTrace();
        // }
        String responseBody = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
//      String responseBody = postMethod.getEntity().
        System.out.println(responseBody);
        postMethod.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Some error message?

Answer (score 1):

If you want users to log into facebook via your site, you need to use the Facebook API, which involves passing tokens back to your server, etc.  Passing a password yourself (if you plan on getting this yourself) is most likely against the terms of service.

If you are trying to automate your own login to facebook, with an HTTP client, that may be a different story.

Comment: I'm trying to automate my own login to facebook, with an HTTP clien

Comment: I want to automate my own login to facebook, with an HTTP clien

Comment: I found the problem  : SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory() insted of SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().  But I still can't get the login page.